# Why the JQuery MatchHeight is not working with RoR?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing maintenance on a old RoR app that uses JQuery MatchHeight all over the place.

But when doing my own page nothing is happen.

This is my view:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail text-center js-matchHeight">
            <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src=
            "image2.jpg">

            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Quick summary of a question that's been asked</h4>
                <p class="date">19 January 2017</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail text-center js-matchHeight">
            <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src=
            "image3.jpg">

            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Quick summary of a question that's been asked</h4>
                <p class="date">19 January 2017</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my ERB loading the scripts:

```
        <% content_for :page_js do %>
            <%= javascript_bundle_tag('shared') %>
            <%= javascript_bundle_tag('product_list_page') %>
            <%= javascript_include_tag('insulation/solution-builder') %>
            <%= javascript_include_tag('insulation/product-list-filter') %>
                <script>
                    $('.js-matchHeightOuter').matchHeight();
                    $('.js-matchHeight').matchHeight();
                </script>

        <% end %>
```

As far as I know, when I loaded this page and look at the inspect, theres should be something like this on the inspector:

```
element.style {
    height: 155px;
}
```

What can I be doing wrong here? Why the MatchHeight its not doing his work?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using it as a DOM ready event? Do the two items actually have different height?

Comment: Seeing that you have `<img>` in your HTML, it's very possible that you're matching the height *before* the images load perhaps. Though, you said it's doing "nothing", and that would probably just calculate the wrong height. Are you seeing any errors in console?

Comment: no errors at console